# Why does declaring a new object give me a syntax error?

Tags: java, arrays, object

I'm in highschool and I'm making a game. I tried to declare a new object:

```
public class Mapgen 
{
    public Checker map[]= new Checker[23];
    
    map[0] = new Checker(red,2);
}
```

but it gave me 2 errors saying:

```
"Syntax error on token ";", { expected after this token"  
"Syntax error, insert "}" to complete ClassBody"
```

I can't figure out what's the problem

thanks for your help

Comment: `map[0] = new Checker(red,2);` probably belongs in a constructor.

Answer (score 1):

You have an assignment statement at class level, where it’s illegal. You need to put it inside a method, e.g. `main`:

```
public class Mapgen {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    public Checker[] map = new Checker[23];
    
    map[0] = new Checker(red,2);
  }
}
```

Note that, unlike the assignment, the variable declaration of `map` *can* be at class level — in which case it’s a member variable. In that case, since `main` is `static`, you’d have to make `map` `static`, too, to be able to access it from `main`.

Answer (score -1):

Your code is not within any method, so
map[0] = new Checker(red,2); makes no sense